# can't login into my codeigniter app after long time of usage

Tags: php, codeigniter

it's been a while since i've purchased freelancer office on codecanyon. i'm using it since 2015. I've never had an issue till last week. If I type in a wrong password it gives me an error (which is normal :D) however when i type the correct one it just reloads the page :/ i've set the ENVIRONMENT to production but no error messages.. except for deprecated each() call in mx/modules.php file.

Codeigniter version: v3.1.0
php version : 7.1

app url:

http://app.wolftech.eu

i've the same error with another 'app' that ive bought on codecanyon for a friend of mine. after 1 year of succesfull usage it just reloads the page when attempting to login.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: did you update your php version?

Comment: After curiosity's question about php version. İ checked on my hosting provider and it seems that one.com has removed php version 5.6 (which i was using) and set it on 7.1. After searching stackoverflow to similar problems ive found that it was a session issue after making some changes to system/libraries/session/session.php and root index.php it works again like a charm.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error output that you've provided, I assume that the error comes from codeigniter modular extension hmvc, that show up because it uses `each()` function that is deprecated.
If you look at one of the [official repository pull request](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/pull-requests/35/replaced-each-function-as-it-is-deprecated/diff), and from [this codeigniter forum thread](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-69505-post-349442.html#pid349442), you could change the `third_party/MX/Modules.php` files line 83 :

```
(is_array($module)) ? list($module, $params) = each($module) : $params = NULL;
```

and replace it to :

```
if(!is_array($module))
{
    $params = NULL;
}
else
{
    $keys = array_keys($module);
    $params = $module[$keys[0]];
    $module = $keys[0];
}
```

Comment: After curiosity's question about php version. İ checked on my hosting provider and it seems that one.com has removed php version 5.6 (which i was using) and set it on 7.1. After searching stackoverflow to similar problems ive found that it was a session issue after making some changes to system/libraries/session/session.php and root index.php it works again like a charm.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also changing the each to if else removed the error. Thank you